# Updating value in a Goroutine

Tags: go

I'm currently working on a personal project to learn Golang, but I'm having some problems when I start to work on Goroutines, I think there are some concepts I'm not undestanding correctly. In short my code has an struct with a receiver function "loop" that does a process every 10 seconds in an infinite loop until the program is terminated, it already works. Now I want to add a simple web server from which I need to be able to update some data inside the struct while the loop is running, here is an abstraction of the problem that I'm using to test the case:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "../thing"
)

var Thing1 thing.Thing

func main() {
    Thing1 := thing.NewThing("thing1")
    //This is the loop that is always running
    go Thing1.Loop()
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.Error(w, "404 Not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
    case "POST":
        if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "There was an error with the form: %v", err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("In handler: " + r.FormValue("fData"))
        Thing1.UpdateData(r.FormValue("fData"))
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
    default:
        http.Error(w, "405 Method not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }

}
```

```
package thing

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Thing struct {
    ID   string
    data string
}

func NewThing(id string) Thing {
    return Thing{ID: id}
}

func (t *Thing) Loop() {
    for {
        now := time.Now().Format("15:04:05")
        fmt.Println(t.ID + " starts at " + now)
        fmt.Println(t.ID + " Data: " + t.data)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    }
}

func (t *Thing) UpdateData(g string) {
    t.data = g
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test control panel</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <label>Data</label><input type="text" name="fData" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, when I push the submit button I want to update the "data" variable in the struct Things1, and that should be reflected when the data variable is printed inside the loop, but it doesn't works, the data variable always prints as empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I think I'm missing some fundamental concept about goroutines. 
Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: It might update, but the value is unsynchronized and the data race makes the output undefined (you also should never use relative import paths, see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html))

Comment: run your code with `-race` flag. dont read/write variables from different routines (http server starts its own set of routines, your `go Thing1.Loop()` is another one). When multiple routines needs to access the same variable, either copy the value over each requester, or synchronize each access so they never overlap. in your case you can implement something like the actors model as described in this blog post https://dave.cheney.net/2016/11/13/do-not-fear-first-class-functions

Answer (score 2):

In your `main` you begin with:

```
Thing1 := thing.NewThing("thing1")
```

This defines a new *local* variable named `Thing1`, as if you had written:

```
var Thing1 Thing
```

and then sets the variable to the result of `thing.NewThing`:

```
Thing1 = thing.NewThing("thing1")
```

Meanwhile your function `HelloServer` does not define any new variable named `Thing1`, but does use the outer (package) scope `Thing1`—a different structure instance, with ID = `""` (empty string) and data = `""`.  When you call `Thing1.UpdateData(r.FormValue("fData"))`, that will pass the address of this empty `Thing1` to the `UpdateData` receiver function.  This unnamed `Thing1` object gets its data updated, while your loop uses the `Thing1` whose ID is `"thing1"`.

That's easy enough to fix: just don't create a *new* `Thing1` in main.  However, as [JimB noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648255/updating-value-in-a-goroutine#comment109048079_61648255), you are not synchronizing your data-update with your data-access, either.  If you're going to communicate by sharing, you need some kind of locking.

([Go encourages sharing by communicating, rather than communicating by sharing.](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/)  This requires a different way of thinking, though.)